# linq group by, order by

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list

```
ID  Counter  SrvID FirstName
--  ------   ----- ---------  
1   34       66M   James
5   34       66M   Keith
3   55       45Q   Jason
2   45       75W   Mike
4   33       77U   Will
```

What I like to do is to order by ID by ascending and then
get the first value of Counter, SrvID which are identical (if any).

So the output would be something like:

```
ID  Counter  SrvID FirstName
--  ------   ----- ---------  
1   34       66M   James
2   45       75W   Mike
3   55       45Q   Jason
4   33       77U   Will
```

Note how ID of 5 is removed from the list as Counter and SrvID was identical to what I had for ID 1 but as ID 1 came first 
I removed 5.

This is what I would do but not working

```
    var result = (from ls in list1
                  group ts by new {ls.Counter, ls.SrvID}
                order by ls.ID
                  select new{
                             ls.ID,
                             ls.Counter.FirstOrDefault(),
                             ls.SrvID.First,
                             ls.FirstName}).ToList()
```

Comment: @ChrisWue - Thanks for tweaking the formatting. How did you format it into a table?

Comment: It's just standard code formatting: indent by 4 spaces

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
list1.GroupBy(item => new { Counter = item.Counter, SrvID = item.SrvID })
     .Select(group => new { 
        ID = group.First().ID, 
        Counter = group.Key.Counter,
        SrvID = group.Key.SrvID,
        FirstName = group.First().FirstName})
     .OrderBy(item => item.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Why do you have a First() next to FirstName and ID?

Comment: GroupBy is going to return you a Counter/SrvID to item lookup, each lookup member has a key (Counter/SrvID) and the associated items. So for each lookup group, you can extract Counter/SrvID from the key and ID and FirstName from the first match in each group.

Comment: @vc74 thank you for your answer. would you be able to elaborate what is going on within the LINQ expression?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon which part of the query to you want me to detail?

Comment: @vc74 hey i've since read an introductory chapter to linq. there is much i don't understand the above. what is happening here: "item => new { Counter = item.Counter, SrvID = item.SrvID }"    ?      I get what item does, but now the instantiation which is going on?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon It basically creates a new instance of a dynamic type (with Counter and SrvID properties) for each item in the source collection. The type automatically built by the compiler has struct semantics meaning that during a comparison, all of its properties are compared, in this case, the items will be grouped by Counter and SrvID.

Comment: Can you please assist me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764687/how-to-use-linq-to-group-by-and-order-by-certain-column

Answer (score 26):

Group the records up, and pick a winner from each group.

```
var query =
  from record in list1
  group record by new {record.Counter, record.SrvID } into g
  let winner =
  (
    from groupedItem in g
    order by groupedItem.ID
    select groupedItem
  ).First()
  select winner;
```

---

```
var otherQuery = list1
  .GroupBy(record => new {record.Counter, record.SrvID })
  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(record => record.ID).First());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - can you please clarify further how var query =   from record in list1  works.. Thanks again

Comment: The first line of this answer is probably the best way I've seen to describe the usage of GroupBy in real English.