# How to group by and order by a collection using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing it this way but it won't work (Do not compile), i need to GroupBy first then OrderBy.

```
lstOrderItems.OrderBy(x => x.itemPrice).GroupBy(p => p.CatID);
```

Comment: Can you specify expected result? Question is not clear - what should be output - sorted groups or items, should you take first ten, or not? Very vague for person with almost 2K rep

Comment: Remove "It doesn't work" from your vocabulary. That's not helpful. It does not tell anybody anything. You need to be precise for people to be able to help you.

Comment: What is this? Linq-To-Entities? Linq-to-Objects?

Comment: linq to object..i have collection of lstOrderItems that each hold orderItem object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq group by, order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132964/linq-group-by-order-by)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem of understanding here. If you do a grouping you'll have a property to work with: the key.

I am taking the northwind database with the products table here as reference. If you Group products by CategoryId `Products.GroupBy (p => p.CategoryID)` you can then append OrderBy of course. But the only property you can order by afterwards is the key:

```
//p.Key is the CategoryId after which you grouped by
Products.GroupBy (p => p.CategoryID).OrderBy (p => p.Key)
```

What you need to do is, is select the grouping and work with it:

```
Products.GroupBy (p => p.CategoryID).Select (p => p.OrderBy (x => x.UnitPrice))
```

If you want to flatten your result use `SelectMany`:

```
Products.GroupBy (p => p.CategoryID).SelectMany (p => p.OrderBy (x => x.UnitPrice))
```

*EDIT*
To clarify the Select/SelectMany issue: This is what you'll get using `Select`. A return type of `IOrderedQueryable<IOrderedEnumberable<Products>>`. In essence a List inside a List.

[image]

If you use `SelectMany()`, you flatten this List inside a List into one List

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the second one that SelectMany that flatten the results.

Comment: I'll give you 2 screenshots from Linqpad in a few minutes which will explain it to you. Otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany

Answer (score 4):

```
var Result = lstOrderItems.GroupBy(p=> p.CatID).Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(d=> d.itemPrice));
```

Comment: If i take this data in result and make any changes on result will it make changes to the lstOrderItems as well?

Comment: No, it wont make changes to lstOrderItems, you have to use the resulted list for further process, what you can do is assign the resulting list to Collection of the same type!