# Selecting first items in GroupBy when using custom Class

Tags: linq

I have a very basic sql view which joins 3 tables: users, pictures, and tags.

How would one create the query below in a way that it won't list the same pictures more than once?  In other words, I want to Group By pictures (I think) and return get the first insance of each.

I think this is very similar to the post [Linq Query Group By and Selecting First Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963707/linq-query-group-by-and-selecting-first-items), but I cannot figure out how to apply it in this case where the query is instantiating MyImageClass.

```
        validPicSummaries = (from x in db.PicsTagsUsers
         where x.enabled == 1
           select new MyImageClass { 
               PicName = x.picname, 
               Username= x.Username, 
               Tag = x.tag }).Take(50);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude duplicates, you can use the `Distinct` LINQ method:

```
validPicSummaries =
   (from x in db.PicsTagsUsers
    where x.tag == searchterm && x.enabled == 1
    select new MyImageClass
    { 
       PicName = x.picname, 
       Username= x.Username, 
       Tag = x.tag
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Take(50);
```

You will need to make sure that the objects are comparable so that two `MyImageClass` objects that have the same `PicName`, `Username`, and `Tag` are considered equal (or however you wish to consider two of them as being equal).

You can write a small class that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you would like to have a custom comparer for just this case. Ex:

```
  private class MyImageClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyImageClass>
  {
     public bool Equals(MyImageClass pMyImage1, MyImageClass pMyImage2)
     {
        // some test of the two objects to determine 
        // whether they should be considered equal

        return pMyImage1.PicName == pMyImage2.PicName
           && pMyImage1.Username == pMyImage2.Username
           && pMyImage1.Tag == pMyImage2.Tag;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(MyImageClass pMyImageClass)
     {
        // the GetHashCode function seems to be what is used by LINQ
        // to determine equality. from examples, it seems the way
        // to combine hashcodes is to XOR them:

        return pMyImageClass.PicName.GetHashCode()
           ^ pMyImageClass.UserName.GetHashCode()
           ^ pMyImageClass.Tag.GetHashCode();
     }
  }
```

Then when you call distinct:

```
    ...
    .Distinct(new MyImageClassComparer())
    .Take(50);
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to exclude Tag so that I just get the first instance of the pic, if it has many tags?  looks good, like I overlooked the obvious solution.  I will get back momentarily...

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure of the meaning of the properties. It's up to you how to consider them to be duplicate.