# Getting first row in every partition in Azure Tables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I want to get only the first rows of every partition in Azure Tables. I can get all the data and then use the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456167/1519458) on that result. What I am asking is "Can I do that on Azure side without getting all that unnecessary results?"

Comment: Do you know the PartitionKey values of the table that you wish to query?

Comment: @GauravMantri I will write a condition based on partition key. That will filter out many records. After that part, what i do not want is getting, say 50, entities per partition key as I only need the first one (ordered by row key) for each partition key.

Comment: @GauravMantri I do not have any information on row key. I just know that I want the one with min row key for each partition key (for the partition keys satisfying the condition).

Comment: @GauravMantri Currently I am eliminating the rows other than the MIN row on the server side(c#) instead of AzureTables side

Comment: I edited the question. Filtering on partition key is not related to what I am asking.

Comment: Is the row key a number?

Comment: @TonyBasallo In my case it is a number (stored as a string). However I have to remind that PartitionKey and RowKey are strings in AzureTable.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to your question is that without knowing the `PartitionKey` in advance, such operation is not possible from the Azure Table side. If you know the `PartitionKey` values, you can query on that value (`RowKey` is not required) and then get single result by specifying `$top=1` (`Take(1)` in LINQ) as one of the querystring parameter.

Comment: And how about a sample of the code to do just that?

Comment: Back here again, and I would still like a code sample... :)