# EF6 Query to latest EF Core could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.1

I have created a query that allows group messages based on the reference number and chose each group's latest record.

```
var list = _context.Messages.Include(m => m.SenderId).Include(m => m.ReceiverId)
.Where(m => m.Status != MessageStatus.Archived)
.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateAdded)
.GroupBy(m => m.Reference)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateAdded).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Can someone suggest how to convert this to EF Core?

Comment: I see you have a lot or reputations and certainly know that you have to show the error message . Only after this people can help you.

Comment: try the updated answer at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834181/how-to-use-linq-or-lambda-with-iqueryable-to-groupby-and-get-the-first-last-reco/64837257#64837257