# How to get fastest time for each Member

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I Know how to produce a list by fastest time by Member (list displays by fastest time). I've also excluded records where time hasn't been entered as per below. But how do I display only the best time for each member? For instance the member named Trevor has the fastest 3 times, but I only want to show the fastest time for each member?

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexFastestTimes()
        {
            var fastesttimes = await _context.MemberData.Where(x => x.Time.Minutes > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToListAsync();
            return View(fastesttimes);
        }
```

For Example the above will return

```
Trevor 24:00,
Trevor 24:05,
Trevor 24:20,
Paul 24:30,
Paul 24:40,
Tim 25:10,
Tim 25:20
```

but I want it to return

```
Trevor 24:00,
Paul 24:30,
Tim 25:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first for each member, you need to use group by as (change time to your member field in group by)

```
 var fastesttimes = await _context.MemberData.Where(x => x.Time.Minutes > 0).GroupBy(x => x.F1, (key,g) => g.OrderBy(e => e.Time).First()).ToListAsync();
```

The above will first grouping based on condition then `.First()` will give the first entry of each group

see other options

[How to get first record in each group using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012986/how-to-get-first-record-in-each-group-using-linq/39932057)

[Linq Query Group By and Selecting First Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963707/linq-query-group-by-and-selecting-first-items/7456167)

Answer (score 0):

```
private class Runner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Runner> runners = new()
    {
        new Runner() { Name = "Trevor", Time = 41 },
        new Runner() { Name = "Trevor", Time = 15 },
        new Runner() { Name = "Trevor", Time = 16 },
        new Runner() { Name = "Paul", Time = 22 },
        new Runner() { Name = "Paul", Time = 12 },
        new Runner() { Name = "Tim", Time = 5 },
        new Runner() { Name = "Tim", Time = 150 }
    };

    Mylist.ItemsSource = runners.Where(x => x.Time > 5).GroupBy(x => x.Name, (x, key) => key.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).First()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @Ajay2707 you got me on the right track. I had to split it into two linq statements as below:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexFastestTimes()
        {
            var times = await _context.MemberData.Where(x => x.Time.Minutes > 0).OrderBy(x=>x.Time).ToListAsync();
            var result = times.GroupBy(x => x.MemberId, (key, g) => g.OrderBy(e => e.Time).First()).ToList();
            return View(result);
        }
```