# How to get one of each type returned from an EF Core query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a list of one of each of the type of notes of a client ordered by desc. In SQL Server, I wrote the following query

```
SELECT  
    note_id, st_id, note_type, signature_date 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         note_id, st_id, note_type, signature_date
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY note_type ORDER BY signature_dateDESC) AS row_num
     FROM 
         notes_log
     WHERE 
         cl_id = 1
         AND svce_type = 'service type 1'
         AND (note_type = 'note type 1' OR note_type = 'note type 2' OR note_type = 'note type 3')
     ) AS subquery
WHERE row_num = 1
ORDER BY signature_date DESC;
```

this query works fine but when converting the above query to Linq im getting some erorrs. Here's what I did

```
 var lastNotes = await dbContext.Set<NotesLog>()
            .Where(s => s.ClientId == id && s.ServiceType == serviceType && (s.NoteType == "type 1" || s.NoteType == "type 2" || s.NoteType == "type 3"))
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.Signaturedate)
            .GroupBy(s => s.NoteType)
            .SelectMany(group => group.Take(1))
            .Select(s => new
            {
                s.NoteId,
                s.StateId,
                s.NoteType,
                s.Signaturedate
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

I also tried swapping the GroupBy and Selectmany with `.DistinctBy(s => s.NoteType)`

both of them returned similar errors

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I know I can first get all notes then query the list to get what I need (I found some such solutions online) it just doesn't make much sense to me to do that. so is there a better way?

EDIT i was able to piece together a solution (see below) where i get the correct results one of each group but the order is inconsistent and it doesn't seem to be ordered descending at all. What i'm looking for is the correct results ordered descending

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK EF Core is not great in terms of translation of `GroupBy`, but you can try first projecting to anonymous type and then using `First` on group:

```cs
var lastNotes = await dbContext.Set<NotesLog>()
    .Where(s => s.ClientId == id && s.ServiceType == serviceType && (s.NoteType == "type 1" || s.NoteType == "type 2" || s.NoteType == "type 3"))
    .Select(s => new
    {
        s.NoteId,
        s.StateId,
        s.NoteType,
        s.Signaturedate
    })
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Signaturedate)
    .GroupBy(s => s.NoteType)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToListAsync();
```

Alternative approache:

Move the SQL into [user-defined  table-valued function and map it to some method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function) so it is supported by SQL

Answer (score 2):

You have several alternatives:

1. Since you already composed the SQL query you can execute it over the recordset and don't crack your head with Linq.
2. You can divide your Linq query and estimate the amount of the intermediate data. If it's acceptable you can process by this way.
3. I didn't think too much on your Linq expression but try to use the 'First' method.

Find more in [Linq Query Group By and Selecting First Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963707/linq-query-group-by-and-selecting-first-items)

Answer (score 2):

between the answers and the links provided I was able to piece together this solution.

```
var lastNotes = await providerContext.Set<NotesLog>()
            .Where(s => s.ClientId == id && s.ServiceType == serviceType && (s.NoteType == "type 1" || s.NoteType == "type 2" || s.NoteType == "type 3"))
            .GroupBy(s => s.NoteType)
            .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(s => s.Signaturedate)
                          .Select(s => new 
                          {
                              s.NoteId,
                              s.StateId,                    
                              s.NoteType,
                              s.Signaturedate
                          })
                          .First()
            ).ToListAsync();
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works
thank you @rotabor and @Guru stron

EDIT this answer works in the sense that it returns the correct dataset but the order of how its returned is inconsistent